# How can I reset DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

My DB2 V10.5 instance on LinuxAMD64 has
[g] DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS
I didn't intentionally set this.

Trying to create a table with ORGANIZE BY COLUMN fails with a message that it can't do this because DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR is set.

I've tried resetting this with
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR= -g
which is accepted but doesn't change the value.

I've tried resetting this with
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR= -g -null
and
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR= -g -null
which fails with DBI1309E System error

How can I reset this?

Answer (score 3):

Try `db2set -g DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=` -- move the option before the variable name. Note that you must be root to change global variables.